# CCleaner shows "Corrupt File" error message

Tags: windows, ccleaner

I get the following warning message when I open CCleaner on Windows XP:

[image]

Why is this coming?

Why does the username end with `.kh`? ("login.kh")

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this coming?

The file or directory is corrupted, as the message itself says. Please run the Chkdsk utility to (hopefully) fix this.

In more detail: CCleaner is trying to read the contents of your Firefox "searchplugins" directory, but Windows is unable to do so due to data corruption. Open *Command Prompt* and run the `chkdsk` command for the C: partition:

`chkdsk C: /f`

Note that `/f`ixing the system partition cannot be done while the system itself is running, so answer <kbd>Y</kbd> to all chkdsk prompts, then reboot, and wait for the repair to complete.

(If you want only to *check* the disk without repairing it, you can run `chkdsk C:`)

---

> Why does the username end with .kh? ("login.kh")

When Windows needs to create a new user profile, but the `yourlogin` directory already exists (for example, if the account existed earlier but was deleted), Windows will not re-use the old profile – it will create a new one with the *computer name* appended. In this case, the `KH` in `yourlogin.KH` is (or was) your computer's name.

In other words, your Windows account was once deleted and re-created.

The computer name can be changed in *My Computer → Properties → Computer Name → Change* in Windows XP.